# Changing value output in unix shell scripting

Tags: unix

My script is reading an input file row by row from start to end in a WHILE loop.

Lets say there is 100 rows in the input file.

when I will run the script, say **script.ksh**

It should show, 1 % completed, when 1 row is read from the input file.
                2 % completed, when 2 rows are read from the input file.
                and show on...

I want to show the percent completion bar from 1 to 100, in a single line output, not in 100 lines.

100 % completed. when the script ran successfully.

**$value** % completed.

here, $value should change from 1 to 100 as per the progress in a single line.

**Example:**

```
in file ipfile.txt, I have
1
2
3
4
.
.
upto
100

count=1
while read line
do
.......
.......
count=`expr $count + 1`
done<ipfile.txt

Here $count value will change from 1 to100.
when I will run the script,
output:
1 % completed. when $count=1
2 % completed. when $count=2
and show on upto 100 %.This completion status should be in single line output.
```

Hope my requirement is clear, let me know if it's need any more explanations.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line_num = 1
while read line; do
    printf "$((line_num++))%% completed\r";
    ...
done < input-file
```

Comment: No clue - but we both got one! :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `seq` command, you can simulate what you want with a script like this.  In this example, the `sleep 1` represents the processing for the line of input.

```
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do echo -e -n "\r$i% completed"; sleep 1
done
echo
```

The `-e` turns on escapes such as `\r` (carriage return); the `-n` suppresses the newline at the end of the `echo`.  Note that the carriage return is at the beginning of the line; it means the cursor rests at the end of the output rather than where the number is and that looks better.  You might prefer to use the `printf` command instead of `echo`; it is likely more reliable.  (This code tested with bash 3.2.)

If you're reading lines, you're going to have to count the percentage complete yourself using shell arithmetic.  If the number of lines in the file is not 100, then you need to scale the values accordingly.

Generally, this is rather too much like hard work to be worth the time spent getting it right.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the reply, I believe you understood my problem.Here I am concentrating on the time the script is being run for.Lets say my script is supposed to run 10 seconds.Then It should show 50 % completed at 5 second.Will it be solved if i am making sleep value to as minimum ?

Comment: Ignore the above comment.I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on ansi escape sequences and use them to manipulate the terminal position.